# CancellationToken Design

Tags: c#, cancellationtokensource

I try to understand the "reason why" cancellationToken is a thing, because my understanding make me thought it's useless.

First, from msdn https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation

[image]

**Question 1** : what is the point of passing the Token at "B" since we use directly at "C" the global variable (declare at "A")
**Question 2** : what is the point of using an "CancellationTokenSource" object since a simple Boolean makes the job like so :

```
if(myBoolCancelRequested){
  //...
  throw new OperationCanceledException()
}
```

Then, still from msdn https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children
It seems I have to pass token to all the call hierarchy and that is what is frutrating me. Suppose I have an **existing** code like so (in separate files and separate classes)

```
main()
    method1()
    |->method2()
    |  |-> method3()
    |  |   |-> DoSomeWork()
```

Converting DomeSomeWork() to be cancelable (like msdn advice) would impact all the code :'(

I expected the framework to provide a powerfull tool, something like (inside the DoSomeWork) :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= maxIterations; i++)
{
   // Do a bit of work. Not too much.
   ....
   ...

   if(Thread.AmazingCurrent?.AmazingCancellationToken?.IsCancellationRequested)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Task {0} cancelled", taskNum);
      //----> **Decide if it's needed to throw exception or just break the loop**
   }
```

**Question 3** : Any opinion of the design behind CancellationToken mecanics?

Comment: Please limit posts to one _objective_ question per post.

Comment: oh sorry i didn't to duplicate half the post for question 1 and 2 as they were related. Should i create 3 posts and relate each other by link or completely separate them ?

Comment: I feel like there's a fundamental misunderstanding of `async` in C# here.

Comment: An external variable is captured in block C. See [Capture of outer variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#capture-of-outer-variables-and-variable-scope-in-lambda-expressions)

Comment: Cancellation is co-operative, you need to tell it exactly where and how often to check for cancellation. You cannot use `myBoolCancelRequested` because there is complex locking/memory barriers involved.

Comment: question 1 and 2 has been 7 years ago. Thanks for having found the solution. For the point 3, as @gunr2171 mentionned i completely forgot the async part if i decide to convert my fuction to be cancelable. As I am in WCF Webservice properly configured for sync (operation behaviors, services behaviors, ) I cannot switch to async so quickly. I will handle the cancelation by hand with no task and a simple check during my loop to get out of function.

Comment: Token at "B" do not pass to task body. It only check on start task.